# Criar plugin JQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou criando um plugin jquery e gostaria de saber como fazer para usar a div selecionada no plugin ser a minha variável...tentei isso :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.plugin = function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var video = this;
            video.contextmenu(function () {
                return false;
            });
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

mas não deu certo, alguém pode me dizer como fazer ?

http://jsfiddle.net/aeBYM/

Comment: Por favor coloque do inicio todo o código relevante à pergunta. Repare que no código que tem agora está a faltar o fecho de uma função `};`

Answer (score 2):

No seu código anterior havia esse erro, além do uso errado do this dentro da closure, como indicado no EDIT logo abaixo.

### Uso do this dentro do método do plugin

Neste caso, o `this` já é o próprio objeto do jQuery.

Ou seja, ao invés de fazer isso `$(this)`, use apenas `this`.

`this` nesse caso é o objeto usado para chamar o método:

```
$("#xpto").dumb( ... );
```

No plugin, `this` se refere ao próprio `$("#xpto")`.

**Referência:**

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

**EDIT:**

### Problema com this na closure

No javascript, o objeto `this` está ligado diretamente ao método atual em execução. Por isso você terá de guardar o objeto do jquery, em uma variável, antes de usá-lo dentro de uma closure:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.dumb = function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var video = _this;
            video.contextmenu(function () {
                return false;
            });
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: o que isso quer dizer ?

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: editei minha pergunta também, sabe pq ele falha quando uso assim ?

Comment: se eu coloco var video = $(this); funciona mas não no script todo, se eu coloco var video = this; não funciona!!

Comment: Como agora você editou a pergunta, essa resposta não faz mais sentido... vou editar a resposta para o novo caso.

Comment: Editei a resposta com informações sobre os erros, e um código que deve funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou sim cara: http://jsfiddle.net/aeBYM/1/ ... se existe algum problema é com esse método `contextmenu`. Mas que ele está sendo chamado está.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou:

```
(function( $ ){ 
    $.fn.dumb = function() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var video = this;
        });
    }
)( jQuery );
```

acredito que possa ser a diferença entre $(this) e this, mas não testei o código...

Comment: editei minha pergunta, veja se consegue ajuda...

Comment: coloca um exemplo completo, pois como você está chamando uma função "contextmenu" e eu não vejo a definição dela, fica mais complicado de ajudar, se não puder colocar o código real do seu problema, muda o nome das variáveis e resume para que possamos ter uma visão mais real do problema ;-)